# (Permutations/Combinatorics )Calculate how many ways these 5 people can now sit if 4 people have to sit 1 seat apart from a certain person...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question:

Four schoolgirls, accompanied by the younger brother of one of them, go to see one
theatrical performance. In the theater, there is a row with 10 vacant seats. They decide to sit down in this row. The four girls decide to sit at least one sit away from the boy,
without it being mandatory to be specified in consecutive positions.

In how many ways these 5 people can now sit?

Comment: Let the boy sit first.  Break into cases based on if the boy sat in one of the edge-seats.  Conclude.

Comment: As an aside, $4+1=5$... not $6$

Comment: Sorry about that I was in a rush... This was what I actually did I assumed that the boy sits at one of the edges then there are but I think I add duplicate combinations.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Since a sufficient hint has already been given breaking into cases, I am giving a simple solution without breaking up into cases.

There is $1$ boy (B), $4$ girls (G), and $5$ vacant seats (V)

- Arrange the $B$ and the $V's$ in $6$ ways, eg one could be  $VVBVVV$
- Wherever the $B$ is placed, the first $G$ can be placed in just $5$ ways, and each $G$ added creates an extra slot for the next $G$ to be placed
- Thus # of valid arrangements $= 6\times5\cdot 6\cdot7\cdot8 = 10,080$

Comment: @Trimidis: Do you understand this approach, avoiding cases  ?

Comment: Yes, i understand it ...But i approached the problem using cases so it's more natural using cases.

Comment: Okay, I tend to try unconventional simple ways. Cheers ! $\;\;$:}

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate between girls; girl1, girl2, girl3, girl4, making it matter  in which order the girls are sat at: $2 \times [8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5] + 8 \times [7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4]$ .

There are two times where the problem changes and that is when the boy sits at the edges, the other 8 positions are the same.